# how to replace the command tfds.load for imdb reviews with download dataset file?

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, tensorflow-datasets

tfds.load(name="imdb_reviews", data_dir=direc, split="train", with_info=True, as_supervised=True)

i have download the dataset , it has downloads and imdb_reviews directories, in the imdb_reviews directory, it has plain_text directory and inside it, exists a directory named 1.0.0 and there are some files inside that. let me say the path to train is: '/content/drive/MyDrive/datasets/packt/imdb/imdb_reviews/plain_text/1.0.0/imdb_reviews-train.tfrecord-00000-of-00001' and the path to test is '/content/drive/MyDrive/datasets/packt/imdb/imdb_reviews/plain_text/1.0.0/imdb_reviews-test.tfrecord-00000-of-00001' , there are also dataset_info.json and features.json and labels.labels.txt and  an unsupervised file, how can I replace the command so that it does not cause other problems. I want to tokenize and encode it with a function

bert_train= [bert_encoder(r) for r,l in imdb_train]

and there is

encoded= tokenizer.encode_plus(text, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=150, pad_to_max_length=True,truncation=True,return_attention_mask=True, return_token_type_ids=True )

inside that encoding function.
thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm a reviewer and I see that you haven't got much response to your questions yet. One very obvious thing that you could improve on is the formatting. It looks like you are not familiar with Markdown, which could make it much more readable. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Also, make sure that basic English grammar rules are followed like starting a sentence with a capital letter. A well formatted and written question usually gets quick responses.

Comment: i found the answer. if you give the directory to the command tfds.load() then the next timme it does not download the dataset because  it finnds out there exits the data in your drive. so there is actualy no need to replace the command with other things.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. if you give the directory to the command `tfds.load()` then the next time it does not download the dataset because it finds out there exits the data in your drive. so there is actually no need to replace the command with other things.